# Button Click events with Dynamic actions in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have created an Edit button with associated Dynamic Action. In the dynamic action, set it to the Click event of the Edit button. I've created the actual action by reference to a JavaScript executing code. And then an update of the area.

In JavaScript code I wanted to enable items that are read only by pressing the edit button.

```
APEX_UTIL.PUBLIC_CHECK_AUTHORIZATION('ADMIN')
```

This was the check I made in the JavaScript code.
In this way I enabled edit mode for the region where I am applying.
ADMIN is a role.

How can I make the button click so that the items associated with the region that are just as read only, when clicking appear in an editable way?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you're reinventing the wheel.

OK, there's the `ADMIN` role (perhaps some other roles as well). If you know which user (identified by `:APP_USER`) has which role, then use

- server-side condition (to decide whether to render (or process) certain page component (items, buttons, ...)
- read only property (to decide whether user will be able to modify the value or not)
- authorization scheme (under "Security")

So, there's no need for the `EDIT` button you currently have. Everything can be done declaratively by setting certain properties within Apex.

Comment: I want to do validation by roles and not by users.

Comment: Every user should have one or more roles, which means that those two terms are closely related. If you know user, you know its role(s). I don't see any problem in that.

Answer (score 0):

this function

```
APEX_UTIL.PUBLIC_CHECK_AUTHORIZATION('ADMIN')
```

is a plsql function, did you use it in your javascript code or as a server side condition?

you can make an ajax request to get the user role using that function and after getting the role in your javascript code you can disable/enable the items using the javascript api.

```
apex.item( "P1_ITEM" ).enable() ;
```

Comment: Where I use this javascript API?

Comment: Does not work.
I click the button and nothing happens :(

Comment: try to create a on click dynamic action that has no condition and set the action to javascript code to execute this for enabling the item `apex.item( "YOUR_ITEM" ).enable();` and for disabling `apex.item( "YOUR_ITEM" ).disable();`

Comment: That's what I did.
I've created an Edit button with dynamic action.
The dynamic action with the button click event.
The real action with the javascript API of my item.
And clicking the button nothing happens. I have no extra validations.

Comment: can you provide a screenshot or can you demonstrate your issue on apex.oracle.com

Comment: [enter image description here][1]


[enter image description here][2]


[enter image description here][3]


[enter image description here][4]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0vpv.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vqLN.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5MDX.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUtWu.png

Comment: wich type of item you want to enable/disable?

Comment: i have demonstrated your issue in my work space and the solution worked for me. you can also demonstrate the problem on [oracle](https://apex.oracle.com/) and give me access